# How to use the Arg<> matcher from the Stub() in the Return()?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Here's what i'd like to do :

```
_service.Stub(s => s.Method(Arg<Dto>.Is.Anything)).Return(new OtherDto { Parent = #My Arg# });
```

How can i replace #My Arg# with the Arg ? If it is even possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Func<Dto, OtherDto> returnOtherDto = dto => new OtherDto { Parent = dto };
_service
    .Stub(s => s.Method(Arg<Dto>.Is.Anything))
    .Do(returnOtherDto);
```

Comment: Does this really work and don't complain about a missing call to `Return`?